# How to customize selected item checkmark icon in SwiftUI Picker in List

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-picker

Using SwiftUI how can I customize the checkmark icon of the selected flavor in this simple Picker?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var flavors = ["orange", "strawberry", "lemon"]
    @State private var selected: String = "orange"

    var body: some View {
        List {
            Picker("Choose a flavor", selection: $selected) {
                ForEach(flavors, id: \.self) {
                    Text($0)
                }
            }
            .pickerStyle(.inline)
        }
        
    }
}
```

[Simple Picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vf3OM.png)

Comment: You would have to create your own Picker with a List

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to create your own custom view inside a list to allow users to select options like this

```
struct ContentView2: View {
    
    var flavors = ["orange", "strawberry", "lemon"]
    @State private var selected: String = "orange"
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(flavors, id: \.self) { flavor in
                Button {
                    withAnimation {
                        selected = flavor
                    }
                } label: {
                    FlavorRow(flavor: flavor, isSelected: flavor == selected)
                        .tag(flavor)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct FlavorRow: View {
    
    var flavor: String
    var isSelected: Bool

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            
            Text(flavor)
            
            Spacer()
            
            if isSelected {
                Image(systemName: "checkmark.seal")
                    .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            }
        }
    }
}
```